# invalid date using Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, datetime, invalidation

Why is 'time' being returned as an invalid date?

```
val = "9/22/2011 4:23 AM"
time = DateTime.parse(val).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").to_datetime
#at breakpoint: time = 2011-09-22T04:23:00+00:00 as a DateTime Object

@form_entry.storage_datetime = time # crashes here with invalid date
```

If it helps, I'm using gem mysql 2.8.1 and Ruby 1.9.2. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an `ArgumentError` on line two; couldn't create the DateTime object in the first place.

Try using [`strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000484) instead:

```
val = "9/22/2011 4:23 AM"
DateTime.strptime(val, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
=> #<DateTime: 2011-09-22T04:23:00+00:00 (3536390423/1440,0/1,2299161)>
```